# Warnings with Fortran generic interface containing procedures whose dummy argment is an unlimited polymorphic pointer

Tags: generics, fortran, polymorphism

I wrote a generic interface which contains three module procedures

```
module MTest
  implicit none
  interface Mesh
    module procedure :: MeshG,MeshR,Meshc
  end interface Mesh
  contains
    logical function MeshR(IVal)
      real(4),intent(in) :: IVal
      MeshR=.true.
    end function MeshR

    logical function MeshC(IVal)
      complex(4),intent(in) :: IVal
      MeshC=.true.
    end function MeshC

    logical function MeshG(IVal)
      class(*),pointer,intent(in) :: IVal
      MeshG=.false.
    end function MeshG
end module MTest

program main
  use MTest
  implicit none
  real(4) :: a
  write(*,*) Mesh(a)
end program main
```

when I compile it with ifort, the compiler gives me two warings:

Test.f90(8): warning #6738: The type/rank/keyword signature for this specific procedure matches another specific procedure that shares the same generic-name.   [MESHR]

```
logical function MeshR(IVal)
```

---------------------^

Test.f90(13): warning #6738: The type/rank/keyword signature for this specific procedure matches another specific procedure that shares the same generic-name.   [MESHC]

```
logical function MeshC(IVal)
```

---------------------^

Since we cannot pass a concrete-typed data,such as real or complex, to an unlimited polomorhpic pointer in a function or procedure calling, I don't quite understand why the compiler gives me such warings. However, it seems that these warnings won't cause any problem in my simple test program. So could anyone explain to me what's going on with these warings and  will they cause any severe problems in some certain cases? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

(A material edit made to the following because I forgot about the restriction in F2008 12.5.2.5p2.)

The rules around selection of an appropriate specific procedure for a generic reference don't consider the current restrictions on pointer and allocatable dummy arguments requiring a match in declared type.

In Fortran 2003 the rules don't even consider the allocatable or pointer nature of the dummy argument.  Specific procedure selection in F2003 is based on the number, name and type+kind+rank of actual arguments.

Therefore, from the point of view of specific procedure selection - because an unlimited polymorphic object is type compatible with anything there is ambiguity in determining which specific procedure should be selected for a reference where the actual argument is real(4) or complex(4).

Compilers are required to diagnose this ambiguity when ever an interface is extended (i.e, as the interface is declared), even if your even if your actual use of the interface is not ambiguous.

(The rules requiring an intent(in) pointer or allocatable argument to match in declared type for polymorphic arguments are also more restrictive than they need be.  If they were to be relaxed in future revisions then an ambiguous reference would certainly be possible.  Having dummy argument disambiguation more restrictive than otherwise required leaves the possibility of backwards compatible language changes in future.)

Answer (score 2):

According to the f2003 standard:

> A nonpolymorphic entity is type compatible only with entities of the same declared type. A polymorphic entity that is not an unlimited polymorphic entity is type compatible with entities of the same declared type or any of its extensions. **Even though an unlimited polymorphic entity is not considered to have a declared type, it is type compatible with all entities**. An entity is said to be type compatible with a type if it is type compatible with entities of that type

so the interface can not be resolved (gfortran returns an error at that point). And so an unlimited polymorphic can have any type, including real.

In the following code you can see an example in which a `CLASS(*), pointer` variable  have real type

```
module mod1
  implicit none
contains
    function fun1(x)
      real,target       :: x
      class(*), pointer ::fun1
      fun1 => x
    end function

    function fun2(IVal)
      class(*),pointer,intent(in) :: IVal
      logical fun2
       fun2=.false.
      select type(IVal)
         type is (real)
            print*, 'type is real'
            fun2 = .true.
      end select
    end function fun2
end module mod1

program main
  use mod1
  implicit none
  real     :: a
  write(*,*) fun2(fun1(a))
end program main
```

returns:

```
 type is real
 T
```

Comment: There is one thing I don't understand that "even though an unlimited polymorphic entity is not considered to have a declared type, it is type compatible with all entities", however, we still can't pass, for example, a real variable or a real pointer to an unlimited polymorphic dummy argument. If we use "write(*,*) fun2(a)" instead of "write(*,*) fun2(fun1(a))" and even declare "a" to be a real pointer, the compiler will still give an error mesaage.

Comment: Intent specification aside, that restriction exists to stop the called procedure from changing the type of the object that the pointer points at (which might then be inconsistent with the type of the actual argument).  If the dummy argument was not a pointer then you could pass a real or complex variable in to a class(*) dummy.